# Runtime for reversing an array in python with [::-1]

Tags: python, time-complexity

I need to reverse a list in python3 using the function below:

```
def flip(arr):
   arr = arr[::-1]
   return arr
```

I would like to know what the runtime for this function is.

Comment: `O(n)` (stack overflow wont let me post a comment less than 15 chars)

Comment: Have you measured it?

Comment: @StephenRauch No but I know it makes a copy, so it cannot be faster than O(n), anything slower would be ridiculous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module

timeit.timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=, number=1000000)

```
>>? def flip(arr):
        arr = arr[::-1]
        return arr

>>? import timeit
>>? timeit.timeit('__main__.flip(range(10000))', 'import __main__', number=1)
0.0005059589886400317
```

Comment: What does the returned time indicate? How can you prove the time complexity with a single value?

Comment: The return time is the runtime for the function in seconds. The time complexity is o(n). You can examine the runtime with variable size input list